# oclif doesn't recognise created commands

Tags: node.js, oclif

I'm trying to build a CLI using oclif and it doesn't seem to work for anything I tried. I see a lot of people making it work for them so can maybe someone point me to my issue!

My steps:

```
 1. mkdir test && cd test
 2. npm init -f
 3. npm i oclif
 4. npx oclif generate my_test //this generates a new cli
 5. cd my_test
 6. npx oclif generate command bob
 7. npm link
 8. npx my_test bob
```

I always get

```
 ›   Error: command bob not found
```

Same if I do `./bin/run bob`

However, if I run the test for the bob command, the test passes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for being late replying... Intel's answer is almost correct - and until version 6 of npm it actually was. Correct is:

```
npm run build
```

Whereas `oclif generate command` just creates the Typescript file for the command and its test class under src/, above will create its Javascript file into dist/. `npm link` does probably nothing to your project at all - just creates a symlink pointing to it. `npm test` makes use of ts-node to directly execute Typescript.

Comment: Thank you!)) I though I was going crazy that no one is complaining about the repo not working besides me :D Was the need to build somewhere in the oclif documentation, that I missed?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Having read the oclif.io documentation only selectively, I haven't seen it mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

run `npm build`, then you have it!

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.